# How can one scroll through multi-line commands in the Zsh history without selecting each line of each command?

Tags: zsh

If one runs the following commands in succession in Zsh (on macOS or Ubuntu):

```
date +%s
```

```
echo \
a\
b\
c
```

One can then scroll back to the first command by pressing the up-arrow 5 times.

Is there a way to scroll back to the first command with just 2 key presses (i.e. the first key press selects the `echo` command and the 2nd key press selects the `date` command)?

When the history contains several long multi-line commands, scrolling back through them with the up-arrow key is a pain.

I was hoping to find some Zsh key shortcuts that would scroll up and down through the command history without stopping en-route to edit multi-line commands, but I haven't yet managed to find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
bindkey '^P' up-history
bindkey '^N' down-history
```

Now you can press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to go up in history and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to go down in history, regardless of how many lines the current editing buffer has or which line you are on.

For more info, see https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control

---

Alternatively, my [`zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) contains a history menu that lets you step up and down through history items, with just one keypress per item, including multi-line items.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. At a glance it looks promising so I’ll take a closer look (and may ultimately come to use it), but I’d prefer to find a solution that doesn’t require installing extra software so it will work on machines running basic Zsh that I don’t own.

Comment: @David I added an alternative solution to the end of my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @David Actually, I found an even better solution for you. I updated my answer again. :)

Comment: Thanks @Marlon, ```bindkey``` is a perfect solution for me; thank you! It works a treat :)